# I wrote this java code to print 2D array in assending order but its printing it in desending order

Tags: java, sorting, multidimensional-array

```
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
         for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
           for(int k=0;k<3;k++){
                for(int l=0;l<3;l++){
                      if(matrix[i][j]>matrix[k][l]){
                       int temp=matrix[i][j];
                       matrix[i][j]=matrix[k][l];
                      matrix[k][l]=temp;
                      
                  }
              }
          }
      }
     }
```

whenever i change '>' with '<' which doesnot make sense in case of assending order ,it print it assending order ?
(same case in 1D)

I was expecting compiler to  print 2D in assending order but compiler printing it in desending order

Comment: the problem are in those for loop ```for(int k=0;k<3;k++){for(int l=0;l<3;l++){```
should be (also a little modification to your if statment) ```for(int k=i;k<3;k++){
                    for(int l=j;l<3;l++){
                        if(matrix[k][l]<matrix[i][j]){```
as your code will rotate the matrix twice it's better to see how it work add break point where the for loop start then from your ide choose debug then step over and you will see how it work

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question correctly, what are you saying,

But to print the array in ascending order try this,

```
    for(int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<matrix.length; j++){
            if(matrix[i] <= matrix[j]){
                int temp = matrix[i];
                matrix[i] = matrix[j];
                matrix[j] = temp;
                
            }
        }
    }
```

And to print in descending order, change matrix[i] <= matrix[j] to matrix[i] > matrix[j]

Comment: the code which you wrote ,here let suppose number at 2 is less then number at 4 then smaller number will move to 4 index and larger number will move to index 2 so actually it seem we are trying to print in desending order actually i am just confuse about how this code is working

Comment: See, when matrix[i] is less than matrix[j] than it is swap otherwise it is not, just skip and continued the loop for another value. You saying reverse. Just try to understand the logic about how both loop working on paper first, then you will get your answer.And after that you should try different algorithms to sorting an array to build logic.